# Como crear un boton Switch on/off en c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2015, checkbox

Estoy intentado crear un swtich on/off para una opalicación de escritorio en C# pero no ecuentro ninguna documentación reciente de esto, solo documentos a medio hacer o los ejemplos que he intentado no han funcionado

Actualmente estoy intentando la con el control Checbox cambiando su apariencia a un boton

```
 cbSound.Appearance = System.Windows.Forms.Appearance.Button;
```

Pero el resultado final no es tan claro para la funcionalidad, lo que intento es que se vea lo mas parecido posible a la siguiente imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Conocen alguna forma de crearlo?
¿Conocen alguna buena documentación al respecto?

Comment: probaste con un boton? rotando la imagen? y usando un bool?? que probaste hasta ahora.. porque esto me suena simple, a menos que no sepamos algo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si ya tienes las imágenes, podrías simular los botones con imágenes haciendo uso de sus eventos MouseClick, MouseEnter, MouseLeave y down, cambiando la imagen en cada uno de ellos

```
boton.Source= new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/imagen1.png")));
```